# Heigher then the page div keep top top/center

Tags: html, css

I have an ajax page that loads like a lightbox on top of the content(a page with lots of products, let's say height=3000px)

That ajax page has a dynamic height, sometimes is 500px, sometimes is 2000px.

Click on a product(load ajax page): if I use position:absolute and I click on a product somewhere at the end of the page I can't really see the ajax page because is too far up. 
If I use position:fixed the ajax page stays on top(doesn't matter the position I'm in) but if the ajax page has a bigger height then the browser height I can't see the ajax page content beyond browser's height :(

Hope this makes sense ...

How Pinterest loads the content when you click on an image is what I want.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Cool, I've done it.

I had to use:

```
#ajax { display:none; position: fixed; width: 100%; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:scroll; z-index: 999999; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;  }
```

And call the ajax:

```
$(".product-list .quickview a").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("body").find("#ajax").load("ajax/product.html").show();
  $(this).closest("body").find(".whitebg").removeClass("hide");
  $(this).closest("body").css({ "overflow" : "hidden"});
})
```